# Flutter Validation and assigning values

Tags: validation, dart, flutter

I'm looking to add validation to my application, but I have no idea to save the data from TextFormField and assign it to _email and _password. I'm very new to coding in Flutter....or coding at all and would really appreciate help.

Can anyone please give me some advice on what to do and get the data validated?

Here is what I have so far, but I cannot get any of the data from the TextFormFields into the assigned String values to use them for validation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ursussupport/home_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'login-page';
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email;
  String _password;

  void _onSubmit() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();

      // Email & password matched our validation rules
      // and are saved to _email and _password fields.
      _performLogin();
    }
  }

  void _performLogin(){

      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomePage.tag);

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final logo = Hero(
      tag: 'avatar',
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 90.0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/niishaw2.jpg'),
      ),
    );

    final email = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Email',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          labelText: null,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)
          )
      ),
    );

    final password = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Password',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)
          )
      ),
    );

    final loginButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          shadowColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade100,
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: 200.0,
            height: 42.0,
            onPressed: _performLogin,
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          )
      ),
    );

    final forgotLabel = FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        'Forgot Password?',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
      ),
      onPressed: (){

      },
    );


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            logo,
            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
            email,
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            password,
            SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            loginButton,
            forgotLabel
          ],
        ) ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextField it has a property onChanged so you can do this and it'll work perfectly for you . 
Use this code sample

```
  final email = TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter Email',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          labelText: null,
      ),
      onChanged: (String str){
        setState((){
          email = str;
        });
      },
    );
```

You can simple add the above shown **onChanged** **property** in your code .

Comment: Thank you so so much for this!!! This has been super helpful!! I was not aware that you had to actually set the state to get the value from the TextField. Now I will start playing around to see if I can actually do some validation using FireBase